# strstr not working in C++ 4.7 on codeforces

Tags: c++, function, strstr, strncpy

On online compiler this program is giving perfect output on giving input `"ABACABA"`, but on Codeforces tests it is just posting the last line. On debugging I found out that the pointer `u` is indicating to address `0` when `strstr()` is used. I am unable to understand why the function is working on other online compiler ,but not on Codeforces.

EDIT: Okay so thanks to @Jeremy Friesner, I found out that it is actually strncpy that is not working properly because now the custom test cases compiler is giving wrong output for 'str'. Still don't know why it should behave differently on two different compilers and what changes should I make.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char *s;
    int length=20;
    s = (char *) malloc(length*(sizeof(char)));
    char c;
    int count=0;
    while((c=getchar())>='A')
    {
        if(c<='Z')
        {
           //cout<<count;
           if(length>=count)
           {
               s = (char *) realloc(s,(length+=10)*sizeof(char));
           }
           s[count++]=c;    
           //printf("%p\n",s);

        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
   }
   char *u=s;
   int o=1;
   //printf("%p\n",s);
   while(u)
   {
       char *str = (char *) malloc(o*sizeof(char));
       str = strncpy(str,s,o);
       //cout<<str<<endl;
       char *t;
       u = strstr(s+1,str);
       //printf("u %p\n",u);
       t=u;
       int ct=0;
       char *p;
       while(t)
       {  
           ct++;
           p=t;
           t = strstr(t+o,str); 
       }

       ct=ct+1;
       //cout<<"here"<<endl;
       if(p==(s+count-o))
       {
           cout<<o<<" "<<ct<<endl;
       }
       //cout<<ct<<endl;
       o++;

   }
   cout<<count<<" "<<1;
}
```

Comment: Try putting a printf("t+o=[%s] str=[%s]\n", t+o, str);  // just before your call to strstr().  That way it will be obvious if the arguments you are passing in to strstr() are not what you think they are.

Comment: You don't null terminate the input string at the end of the input loop; you invoke undefined behaviour.  The memory returned by `malloc()` and `realloc()` is not guaranteed to be zeroed.

Comment: `getchar()` returns an `int`. You should store the result in an `int` object so you can distinguish the `EOF` value it returns to indicate there are no more characters to be read from any valid character value.

Comment: Why do you set `str` to the return of `malloc`, but then throw that result away by re-assigning `str` on the next line?!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am sorry, but I didn't understand your comment. What changes in the code are you suggesting?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I admit that the str=stncpy() is redundant. It has no effect on the value of str. I will remove the "str=" from the code.

Comment: It would help if you explained what this is supposed to do.

Comment: Before `char *u=s;` add `s[count] = '\0';`. Strictly, you should also check the return values from both `malloc()` and `realloc()`, and you leak memory if `realloc()` fails.

Comment: @user657267 It is a solution to this http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/432/D problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler THANKS A LOT. I was only allocating 'o' characters to str and so str didn't have an '\0' at the end. That is why it was showing wrong value for str.

Comment: Also note that you have `if(length>=count)` round the wrong way, as length is always bigger than count. This won't cause the issue you are seeing, but it does mean you are doing an awful lot of reallocs of up to 10 x the length of your string.

Comment: @user3642625: **None of the functions is "not working properly"**. You are *using* them wrongly, in a way that invokes undefined behaviour. Sometimes you get unlucky, and undefined behaviour does not make your program crash immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, a principal problem was that you were not null-terminating the string after you read it in, which leads to odd results.  Specifically, it leads to you invoking *undefined behaviour*, which is always a bad thing.  The memory allocated by `malloc()` and the extra memory allocated by `realloc()` is not guaranteed to be zeroed.

You can fix the problem by adding:

```
s[count] = '\0';
```

just before:

```
char *u = s;
```

Strictly, you should also check the return values of both `malloc()` and `realloc()`.  Also, you should not use the idiom:

```
x = realloc(x, newsize);
```

If the `realloc()` fails, you've lost your pointer to the original data, so you've leaked memory.  The safe way to work is:

```
void *space = realloc(x, newsize);
if (space == 0)
    …report error etc…
x = space;
x_size = newsize;
```

There may be other problems; I've not scrutinized the code for every possible issue.

Answer (score 1):

You never put null-termination after the characters you put into `s`, therefore `s` does not contain a string. So it causes undefined behaviour to pass it to a function that expects a string, such as `strncpy`.

Another big problem is your usage of `strncpy`.

```
int o=1;

while(u)
{
   char *str = (char *) malloc(o*sizeof(char));
   str = strncpy(str,s,o);
   u = strstr(s+1,str);
```

The `strncpy` function does not create a string, if `strlen(s) >= o`. In this case, the `strstr` function will just read off the end of the buffer, causing undefined behaviour. (Exactly what happens will depend on your compiler and on what junk was in this piece of memory).

You need to put a null-terminated string into `str`.  Either manually add a null-terminator:

```
assert(o > 0);
strncpy(str, s, o-1);
str[o-1] = 0;
```

or use a different function:

```
snprintf(str, o, "%s", s);
```

You have to keep in mind that **a string is a series of characters followed by a null terminator**. Whenever you work with functions that expect strings, it's up to you to make sure that the null terminator is present.

Also be careful with lines like `strstr(t+o,str);`. If `o > strlen(t)` this causes undefined behaviour. You've got to do the checking yourself that you do not go outside the bounds of the string.